# dropdown Calendar in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched all over the net and have found examples of a dropdown calendar, however it didn't work in any of the web browsers.

I then used:-

```
<input type="date">
```

it works perfectly on google chrome, but not on the other browsers.

Comment: Because `<input type="date">` renders the browsers  HTML5 datepicker and its not supported in IE or Firefox (and only in recent versions of Chrome). And you can use [this site](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-34/opera-24/ie-11.html) to make comparisons of which types are supported in which browsers

Answer (score 1):

you are using html 5 datepicker, but not all browser implement datepicker.

if you want to make sure all browser show a calendar, why not use 3rd party such as jquery datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/